# How to auto-reload/hotswap with gradle and scala?

Tags: scala, gradle, hotswap

I have a Scala server application that uses gradle and [scala](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/scala_plugin.html) and [application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugins for build and running. I start the application with `gradle run`.

A part of my gradle. A typical one, really:

```
...
apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'application'
...
mainClassName = "mypackage.Main"
```

**How to automatically re-compile and restart the application whenever I modify the source code?**
Preferably, using the CLI and gradle without any IDE usage. Also, I've heard a similar feature is in sbt, but I'm not intending to use sbt.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use the **--continous** tag solution :

In a terminal:

```
gradle build --continuous
```

In an other terminal:

```
gradle run
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work :(. It does rebuild, but the running application isn't restarted nor affected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd tried `gradle run --continuous` but didn't work because the `run` task is never-ending and seems like `--continuous` doesn't start a new build/task unless the previous one has finished.

So, the closest solution I could reach is:

- Add an endpoint that shuts down the application.
- Make a setup such that you can call the endpoint with one click.
- Run `gradle run --continuous`.
- If you make edits to the source code and want to restart the application, call the endpoint.

Yes, that's not exactly "automatically re-compiling and restarting" but that's the closest I could reach. Also, of course, don't keep needless endpoints in your code; either make it automatic to be unavailable in production, or don't apply this solution in the first place.